# Determining the set after switching coordinates

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $$S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3:x \gt0,\  y\ge1,\ z\ge1,\ xyz\le 1\}$$

I need to find the set $S^*$ that you get when you transform the set $S$ in this way: $$ x=u,\  y=\frac{u+v}{u},\ z=\frac{u+v+w}{u+v}$$

By just rewriting the conditions of $S$ I got $$S^*=\{(u,v,w) \in \mathbb R^3:u>0,\ v\ge0,\ w\ge0,\ u+v+w\le1\}$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: No.  (1/2, 0, 0) is in S* but not in S.  Solve for u,v,w in terms of x,y,z.

Comment: @William Elliot why do the sets need to be equal

Comment: If you change coordinates of a circle from rectangular to polar coordinates does  the circle change?